# Sort a List of json objects in FLutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new in Flutter , i want to sort a list that came from json data , i am trying to sort my teams data by goals , like the most teams that scored will be the first on the list , and the second .....
until the last one.

the problem is i do not have any idea except how to access goals attribute:
teamgoals = teams[index of the team].league.standings[0][0].all.goals.goalsFor;

here the function that call the teams api:

```
 Future<void>  getStandings() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=39&season=2020',
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key,
          'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      teams = clubList
          .map((dynamic item) => TeamsJson.fromJson(item))
          .toList();
      teamgoals = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].all.goals.goalsFor.toString()+" "+"Goals";
      teamname =  teams[0].league.standings[0][0].team.name.toString();
      teamphoto = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].team.logo.toString();
      teampoints = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].points.toString()+" "+"Pts";

    });


Here the full code of the app:

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/Key/Key.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/clubs/Clubs.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/news%20copy/topScorers.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/results/results.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/schedules/schedules.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_goals.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/teams_json.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/tables%20copy/league_board.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_assists.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_red_cards.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_yellow_cards.dart';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'assist_json.dart';
    import 'goals_json.dart';
    
    
    
    class Statss extends StatefulWidget {
    
    
      @override
      _StatssState createState() => _StatssState();
    }
    
    class _StatssState extends State<Statss> {
    
      List<AssistsJson> topassists = [];
      List<GoalsJson> topgoals = [];
      List<TeamsJson> teams = [];
      List<String> data = [];
      List<Choices> menu = [];
      String assister;
      String assisterphoto;
      String scorerphoto;
      String assists;
      String goals;
      String scorer;
      String teamgoals;
      String teamname;
      String teamphoto;
      String teampoints;
    
    
      Future<void>  getScorers() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players/topscorers?league=39&season=2020',
            headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key,
              'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
        String body = response.body;
        var data = jsonDecode(body);
        List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];
    
        setState(() {
          topgoals = clubList
              .map((dynamic item) => GoalsJson.fromJson(item))
              .toList();
          goals = topgoals[0].statistics[0].goals.total.toString();
          scorer = topgoals[0].player.name+" "+topgoals[0].player.firstname;
          scorerphoto = topgoals[0].player.photo;
        });
    
      }
    
      Future<void>  getStandings() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=39&season=2020',
            headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key,
              'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
        String body = response.body;
        var data = jsonDecode(body);
        List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];
    
        setState(() {
          teams = clubList
              .map((dynamic item) => TeamsJson.fromJson(item))
              .toList();
          teamgoals = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].all.goals.goalsFor.toString()+" "+"Goals";
          teamname =  teams[0].league.standings[0][0].team.name.toString();
          teamphoto = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].team.logo.toString();
          teampoints = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].points.toString()+" "+"Pts";
    
        });
    
      }
    
      Future<void>  getAssisters() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players/topassists?league=39&season=2020',
            headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key,
              'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
        String body = response.body;
        var data = jsonDecode(body);
        List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];
    
        setState(() {
          topassists = clubList
              .map((dynamic item) => AssistsJson.fromJson(item))
              .toList();
          assists = topassists[0].statistics[0].goals.assists.toString();
          assister = topassists[0].player.name+" "+topassists[0].player.firstname;
          assisterphoto = topassists[0].player.photo;
    
        });
    
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getScorers();
        getAssisters();
        getStandings();
    
    
    
      }
    
    
    
    
    
    
      List<String> images = [
        "Assets/tt.jpg",
        "Assets/qatarairways.jpg",
        "Assets/LOGO_Danao.jpg",
        "Assets/delice.jpg"
      ];
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
             List<Choices> menu = [
               Choices("Top Scorer: ", goals.toString(), topgoals[0].player.name,topgoals[0].player.photo.toString()),
               Choices("Top Assister: ", assists.toString(), topassists[0].player.name,topassists[0].player.photo.toString()),
               Choices("Top Team Goals ", teamgoals.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
               Choices("1 st Team ", teampoints.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
             ];
    
             return teams.length == 0 || topassists.length == 0 || topgoals.length == 0
                 ? Container(
               color: Colors.white,
               child: Center(
                 child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                   valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                     Color(0xFFe70066),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             )
                 :Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Stats"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
            body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Statistiques",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: menu.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Card(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          elevation: 4.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            //padding:  EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child:
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(menu[index].image),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child:
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(menu[index].title+" "+menu[index].name,style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            color: Colors.white),),
                                      )
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child:  Text(menu[index].record, style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                        color: Colors.white),),
                                  )
    
    
                                ),
    
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
    
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 30, 15, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Top Scorers",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scorers()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Top Assists",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Assists()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Yellow Cards",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YellowCards()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Red Cards",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RedCards()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Team Stats",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LeagueBoard()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: images.length,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Image.asset(images[index]);
                        },
                      ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
    
    
    
    
    class Choices {
      String title;
      String record;
      String name;
      String image;
    
      Choices(this.title,this.record,this.name,this.image);
    
    }


My problem is that i can not sort my list of teams by goals or wins or  anything , i am trying to find the way about how to do it,

Here my model class using quicktype:

    // To parse this JSON data, do
    //
    //     final teamsJson = teamsJsonFromJson(jsonString);
    
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    List<TeamsJson> teamsJsonFromJson(String str) => List<TeamsJson>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => TeamsJson.fromJson(x)));
    
    String teamsJsonToJson(List<TeamsJson> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
    
    class TeamsJson {
      TeamsJson({
        this.league,
      });
    
      League league;
    
      factory TeamsJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TeamsJson(
        league: League.fromJson(json["league"]),
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "league": league.toJson(),
      };
    }
    
    class League {
      League({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.country,
        this.logo,
        this.flag,
        this.season,
        this.standings,
      });
    
      int id;
      String name;
      String country;
      String logo;
      String flag;
      int season;
      List<List<Standing>> standings;
    
      factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => League(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        country: json["country"],
        logo: json["logo"],
        flag: json["flag"],
        season: json["season"],
        standings: List<List<Standing>>.from(json["standings"].map((x) => List<Standing>.from(x.map((x) => Standing.fromJson(x))))),
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "country": country,
        "logo": logo,
        "flag": flag,
        "season": season,
        "standings": List<dynamic>.from(standings.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x.toJson())))),
      };
    }
    
    class Standing {
      Standing({
        this.rank,
        this.team,
        this.points,
        this.goalsDiff,
        this.group,
        this.form,
        this.status,
        this.description,
        this.all,
        this.home,
        this.away,
        this.update,
      });
    
      int rank;
      Team team;
      int points;
      int goalsDiff;
      String group;
      String form;
      String status;
      String description;
      All all;
      All home;
      All away;
      DateTime update;
    
      factory Standing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Standing(
        rank: json["rank"],
        team: Team.fromJson(json["team"]),
        points: json["points"],
        goalsDiff: json["goalsDiff"],
        group: json["group"],
        form: json["form"],
        status: json["status"],
        description: json["description"],
        all: All.fromJson(json["all"]),
        home: All.fromJson(json["home"]),
        away: All.fromJson(json["away"]),
        update: DateTime.parse(json["update"]),
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rank": rank,
        "team": team.toJson(),
        "points": points,
        "goalsDiff": goalsDiff,
        "group": group,
        "form": form,
        "status": status,
        "description": description,
        "all": all.toJson(),
        "home": home.toJson(),
        "away": away.toJson(),
        "update": update.toIso8601String(),
      };
    }
    
    class All {
      All({
        this.played,
        this.win,
        this.draw,
        this.lose,
        this.goals,
      });
    
      int played;
      int win;
      int draw;
      int lose;
      Goals goals;
    
      factory All.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => All(
        played: json["played"],
        win: json["win"],
        draw: json["draw"],
        lose: json["lose"],
        goals: Goals.fromJson(json["goals"]),
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "played": played,
        "win": win,
        "draw": draw,
        "lose": lose,
        "goals": goals.toJson(),
      };
    }
    
    class Goals {
      Goals({
        this.goalsFor,
        this.against,
      });
    
      int goalsFor;
      int against;
    
      factory Goals.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Goals(
        goalsFor: json["for"],
        against: json["against"],
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "for": goalsFor,
        "against": against,
      };
    }
    
    class Team {
      Team({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.logo,
      });
    
      int id;
      String name;
      String logo;
    
      factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Team(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        logo: json["logo"],
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "logo": logo,
      };
    }
```

Any help will be so appreciated.

Comment: Implement a model class for json. Implement Comparable interface and then sort it

Comment: i have a model class already but i do not know how to do the comparable class and the sort , can you show me an example? the model class in on the last of the code

Comment: How do you want to sort ? On what  basic you want to decide that this is bigger than other. By some `id` or 'rank' or anything else ?

Comment: ok let's use the goalsFor as an example for demonstration , here how to access it teams[index of the team].league.standings[0][0].all.goals.goalsFor;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

Implement a model class for json. Implement Comparable interface and then sort it.

Now that you have already have modal class. I have taken a dummy class to explain how to implement this

```
class Student implements Comparable {
  int marks;
  String name ;

  Student(this.marks,this.name);


  @override
  int compareTo(other) {

    if (this.marks < other.marks) {
      return 1;
    }

    else if (this.marks > other.marks) {
      return -1;
    }

    else{
      return 0;
    }
  }
}


void main(){
  List<Student> myList = [];
  myList.add(Student(20,"A1"));
  myList.add(Student(-1,"A2"));
  myList.add(Student(-340,"A3"));
  myList.add(Student(-30,"A4"));
  myList.add(Student(2340,"A5"));
  
  print('Before sort');
  for(var item in myList){
    print(item.marks.toString()+"   "+item.name);
  }
  
  
  myList.sort();
  
   print('After sort');
   for(var item in myList){
    print(item.marks.toString()+"   "+item.name);
  }
  
    Comparator<Student> nameSorter = (a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    
    myList.sort(nameSorter);
  
  print('After sort by name');
   for(var item in myList){
    print(item.marks.toString()+"   "+item.name);
  }
}
```

You can run this code

https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true here

Comment: can i create a lot of criteria to sort?  like sort by goals or sort by rank etc ..

Comment: @FaresBenSlama Sure you can. I have updated the code. Not try to run it again

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to sum up all goals for the league firstly. And then sort the teams list with the goals.

```
class League {
  int get allGoals {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < standings.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < standings[i].length; j++) {
        sum += standings[i][j].all.goals.goalsFor;
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

teams.sort((t1, t2) {
  return  t1.league.allGoals > t2.league.allGoals ? 1 
    : (t1.league.allGoals < t2.league.allGoals -1 : 0);
});
```